# How to configure Printer Settings from JavaScript for IE?

Tags: javascript, html, printing, size

I have an web application which print pages. But I want pages to be of different paper size like A5, A4, A3, etc. I want to set it from JavaScript and not manually. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Only way I know of is http://scriptx.meadroid.com/

If that is not an option then the answer is: not possible

Alternative is to return PDFs in the format you want and allow the user to print "original format"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overwrite the default/user print configuration .

But you can include a css specific to only print

```
<link media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somePrint.css"/>
```